# How to feed a Jmol script with input arguments from command line

Tags: command-line, arguments

The `--script` option of Jmol executes a given script, like this:

```
$ ./jmol.sh --nodisplay --script ~/.jmol/macros/myscript.spt
```

Is there a way to input values into the script as command line arguments, such that they can be used (like the variable `_arguments_` array, when invoking a Jmol function) in the script?

Answer (score 0):

There is not such functionality in Jmol, but as suggested [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jmol/feature-requests/262/#8dae) a roundabout would be to assign value to the variables before the script is invoked, like this:

```
$ ./jmol.sh --nodisplay -J "v1='test';v2='now'" --script ~/.jmol/macros/myscript.spt
```